OK, an how to reload the cuttent php page with all POST variables?
OK, the above explains a lot, but could somebody give an advice how to reload the current php page with all POST variables, of which I have little control which they are ?
With:
$url = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&   $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https://" : "http://";
$url .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header ('Location: ' . $url);
alone, they are lost.

Well, I guess this has no simple answer, because such things are done better with AJAX / javascript, am I correct ?
